# How to set reference to object as a class member?

Tags: c#, .net, ref

I am trying to write a loop that can set members in a class. For that I need to declare another class with references to the first class members. I know how to do it in C, but how do you do it in C#?

It's best to explain it with the following pseudo-code sample:

```
class ConfigData
{
    public bool v0;
    public string v1;
    public string v2;
    public int v3;
    //...
    public int vN;
}
    
enum ObjType
{
    COT_string,
    COT_int,
    COT_bool,
}
    
class PropToObj
{
    public string strPropName;
    public ref object objVal;      // ERROR HERE <----
    public ObjType type;
}
    
    
ConfigData cfg = new ConfigData();
    
PropToObj[] cfps = new PropToObj[]
{
    new PropToObj() { strPropName = "VAL0", objVal = ref cfg.v0, type = ObjType.COT_bool },
    new PropToObj() { strPropName = "VAL1", objVal = ref cfg.v1, type = ObjType.COT_string },
    new PropToObj() { strPropName = "VAL2", objVal = ref cfg.v2, type = ObjType.COT_string },
    new PropToObj() { strPropName = "VAL3", objVal = ref cfg.v3, type = ObjType.COT_int },
    // ....
};
    
string strVal;
    
//Set members in 'cfg' class:
for(int i = 0; i < cfps.Length; i++)
{
    strVal = session[cfps[i].strPropName];
    
    switch(cfps[i].type)
    {
        case ObjType.COT_string:
            cfps[i].objVal = strVal;    //Must set member in 'cfg' class
            break;
    
        //.....
    }
}
```

Comment: just ommit the `ref` from your member and your assignements. You can set the field anyway as it's publicicly declared. If you wanted to avoid that, you'd better off using a **property** that has a getter and a (`private`)  setter.

Comment: @HimBromBeere hmm. Which 'ref' should I omit?

Comment: If you want an instance of PropToObj to be able to change the values of a property inside an instance of ConfigData then put the whole instance of config data inside PropToObj. You don't even need the array anymore. Why do you need to get the _ref_ of a single property?

Comment: @HimBromBeere just tried it. And the code above did not change my `cfg` object.

Comment: You can't have an (internal) reference like `cfg.v0`, or rather, you can, but not without unsafe code -- and it can't be done through `ref object`, as that's not valid. A `ref bool` would require a different access pattern (there is no `void*` equivalent). The C# approach would usually be to bounce through a delegate instead (`Action<TObj, TProp>` to encapsulate a setter), or an expression tree, or other forms of reflection. It's likely you need a completely different approach to whatever it is you're trying to achieve, sans the C-ism baggage. Maybe deserialize some JSON, even.

Comment: @JeroenMostert yes probably. C# is not my first language.

Comment: For a first approach, see if you really need to work through an object at all -- a `Dictionary<string, object>` is not type safe, but convenient. If you do want typed access, look at pre-cooked libs that do deserialization, from any convenient format (like JSON). If none of that takes your fancy and it's not performance critical, consider `ExpandoObject` and `dynamic` for semi-typed access. If you do need perf, you'll have to look into reflection, but there's a learning curve there if it needs to be fast; a lib like `FastMember` may be of help there (but do consider other things first).

Comment: @JeroenMostert No need. Thanks. Ill just replace it with a long if-else statement.

Comment: C# can at least `switch` on strings (unlike C), so you may want to consider that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's change your PropToObj class to be like this one

```
public class PropToObj
{
    private List<string> propNames { get; set; }
    private List<ObjType> types { get; set; }
    private ConfigData data { get; set; }

    // We receive the instance of ConfigData to work on and the list of the
    // real fields names with their types. This could be the constructor 
    // of PropToObj as well        
    public void Initialize(ConfigData cfg, List<string>names, List<ObjType> tp)
    {
        propNames = names;
        types = tp;
        data = cfg;
    }

    // It is unclear what is the _session_ type here, 
    // just set the correct type for the parameter
    public void SetValues(???type??? session)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < propNames.Count; i++)
        {
            object val = session[propNames[i]];
            // To change the Fields we make use of a couple 
            // of Reflection lines to get the reference 
            // to the field to change it through a FieldInfo instance

            FieldInfo fi = data.GetType().GetField(propNames[i]);
            fi.SetValue(data, val);    
        }
    }
}
```

Now we can use just one instance of PropToObj to do all the work required on a single instance of ConfigData.

```
ConfigData cfg = new ConfigData();
PropToObj cfps = new PropToObj();
cfps.Initialize(cfg, new List<string> { "v0", "v1", "v2", "v3" },
                     new List<ObjType> { ObjType.COT_bool, ObjType.COT_string, 
                                         ObjType.COT_string, ObjType.COT_int});

.....                                             
cfps.SetValues(session);
```

The ObjType is not really required but I kept it anyway if you need it for some very type specific task.
Usually this should be done using Properties and not Fields so
I would change the ConfigData Fields adding a {get;set} to change the Fields in Properties and then use GetProperty to obtain a PropertyInfo instance in place of FieldInfo and GetField